# Properties of anonymous objects

Tags: c++

Say i have a class array_adder, what is the difference if i create an anonymous object of this class and a named object?
Do the scopes change?

code overloading the standard + operator:

```
template<typename LEFT, typename RIGHT>
array_adder<LEFT< RIGHT> operator+(LEFT& l, RIGHT& r){
return array_adder<LEFT,RIGHT>(l,r);

}
```

a+b will create an anonymous object of template class array_adder.
Are there any differences between anonymous objects and named objects?

Comment: Returning a reference to a local object is undefined behaviour. That holds true whether the object is anonymous or named.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please upvote so i dont get banned pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the problem of returning a reference to a local object cited above, there is no difference in scope or anything else. Assuming the compiler is able to properly resolve your `LEFT` and `RIGHT` types, the `array_adder` template will be instantiated into an ordinary class, and then the constructor is called to create the object of that class that you're returning.

If you make the function return by instance rather than reference, you can take advantage of move optimisation if the template allows it.

The other thing to note is that you have the addition operator taking non-const references to `LEFT` and `RIGHT` objects. In most cases, we expect an ordinary addition operation *not* to modify its arguments, so it's a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please upvote so i dont get banned pls

Answer (score 0):

Temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the full expression where the temporary is created (except when a reference is bound to that temporary in which case the lifetime of the temporary is extended to that of the reference. That is not what happens here).

The returned reference will refer to the object that was destroyed at the end of the function, and the behaviour of using the referred object (there isn't actually an object anymore) is undefined. The reference is said to be *dangling*.

It is unclear what you mean by *"difference if i create ... a named object"* exactly. But if you're suggesting to create a local variable with automatic storage duration, then that would also be destroyed at the end of the function, and the returned reference would be dangling.

As both suggestions simply return a dangling reference, any further comparison is pointless.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please upvote so i dont get banned pls